# Copy tools from nuget package to bin folder

Tags: nuget

I have some automated tests that are using Selenium WebDriver. Tests should run on Chrome so I need to have ChromeDriver.exe. I am using NuGet to download the libraries and found that the ChromeDriver could be downloaded as a package too (http://www.nuget.org/packages/WebDriver.ChromeDriver).

However, this package contains only ChromeDriver.exe in the Tools folder. I need to copy this file into the bin folder because tests need to find it. Is there some way to do the copy in a generic way (without specific paths), because in the folder where the ChromeDriver.exe is unpacked from package contains version number so I would need to change the paths when the new version will be used. Also I would need to do similar thing with the NUnit.Runner package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably use a [post-build event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke5z92ks.aspx). Then inside the event use `copy`/`xcopy` and move it into the bin folder after the project has successfully built.

Comment: This is where I ended. In my Install.ps1 I am adding xcopy commands into post-build event and also I am removing them by Unintall.ps1. So I should have correct paths after update-package command.